# .net core 2.2 Connection processing ended abnormally. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (125): Operation canceled

Tags: c#, .net, docker, google-app-engine

I seem to get this error when deploying to a docker container running in Google App Engine.
The api responds to requests for a while, then all of a sudden stops with the error below.

```
A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z       Connection processing ended abnormally.

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (125): Operation canceled

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.ProcessSends()

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoSend()

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.BeginRead(ValueTask`1& awaitable)

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

A 2020-02-03T09:53:39Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Docker File:

```
# Use Microsoft's official .NET image.
# https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet

FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:2.2.8

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://+:8080;"

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll"]
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

On my local machine this error does not appear. Only in docker container.

Comment: Try to put ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS as following: ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080. I think by mistake you put + instead of *.

Comment: Thanks for your response @NibrassHaider. I just tried that and I still get the same error after a few requests. I've also added the KnownProxies as per the Google App Engine docs as well as app.UseForwardedHeaders(), but still same result

Comment: Have a look into the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/runtime)  for .NET.                                           Also try to put runtime as aspnetcore.

Comment: Why are you using api.dll instead of Metadata.dll?

Comment: @NibrassHaider i've used the aspnetcore runtime. Still same issue. Metadata.dll? I'm using the dll produced when published. i just replaced the real dll name with 'api.dll'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion about dll file. I deployed an app with custom runtime with aspnetcore:2.2.8 and it worked fine for me. Can you share the structure of your project ? Where do you create the Dockerfile, I  mean in which directory?

Comment: No problem. Currently, its manually added to the publish directory. The API accepts requests via the controller, which calls a class library that fetched data from Cloud SQL

Comment: When you experience the dropping connection, is this correspond in anyway to high traffic? or any particular time of the day? Do the connections start working again or do you need to do anything like re-deploying ?